# Passing values to the insert query with select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert two values in the a table.One of which is actually taken from another table with the select statement as below.

```
query = "INSERT INTO empallowance(emp_id_fk,allowance_id_fk) VALUES(SELECT emp_id FROM employee WHERE emp_cnic='" + cnic + "',@allowance_id_fk)";
```

There is syntax error exception as shown in the figure.

[image]

Comment: Please attach the error as a string and not from the picture - will make it easier for people to understand

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement is invalid. Use the following:

```
query = "INSERT INTO empallowance SELECT emp_id, @allowance_id_fk FROM employee WHERE emp_cnic='" + cnic + "'";
```

You can read all about the approach [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp).

Answer (score 1):

you have to use bracket in sub query.
try this:

```
  query = "INSERT INTO empallowance(emp_id_fk,allowance_id_fk) VALUES((SELECT emp_id FROM employee WHERE emp_cnic='" + cnic + "'),@allowance_id_fk)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way but you can create a select statement and [insert its results](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp):

```
"INSERT INTO empallowance (emp_id_fk,allowance_id_fk)
select emp_id, @allowance_id_fk 
from employee 
WHERE emp_cnic='" + cnic + "'"
```

Also, take note, using string concatenation to insert the parameter is vulnerable for SQL Injections - Use [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) instead

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query as below :

```
query = "INSERT INTO empallowance(emp_id_fk,allowance_id_fk) SELECT emp_id, @allowance_id_fk FROM employee WHERE emp_cnic= ' " + cnic + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add '()' between select query for a separation of insertion query.

```
INSERT INTO empallowance(emp_id_fk,allowance_id_fk) VALUES((SELECT emp_id FROM employee WHERE emp_cnic='" + cnic + "'),@allowance_id_fk)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by this, it worked for me

```
query = "INSERT into TABLE1 (name,city) 
Select name, 'Paris' from TABLE2 where id = 1";
```

you can assign values directly in a select query.